# как установить PyGame в Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame

Нашёл старый комп, установил ubuntu 10.04 LTS(другие логают) и не знаю как скачать PyGame туда.

Comment: программа `apt-get` сама «скачает» из репозитория. пакет называется `python-pygame`.

Comment: Пишет - 'E: Не удалось найти пакет python-pygame'

Comment: вероятно, у вас неправильно ссылки на репозитории указаны. в файлах `/etc/apt/sources.list*`. вместо `http://archive.ubuntu.com` (и подобного) должно быть `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com`. после исправления надо, естественно, получить список пакетов: `$ sudo apt-get update`

Comment: пробовали Lubuntu? (Для 15.10 минимальные требования: Pentium II, 128MB, 2GB). Иначе попробуйте себе miniconda поставить, а всё остальное (включая сам python) уже через conda

Answer (score 0):

Можно установить `python-pygame` Ubuntu пакет, если вы измените ссылки на репозитории [как @alexander barakin предложил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591844/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-pygame-%d0%b2-ubuntu-10-04-lts#comment795425_591844). Выполните как root:

```sh
# sed -i 's/archive/old-releases/' /etc/apt/sources.list
# apt-get update
# apt-get install python-pygame -y
```